# Sql - How to search for distinct rows that have two specific variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to read tutorials and find question on syntax on sql subqueries for a specific purpose but I can't seem to find the right choice of words to describe my problem.

Table - Part Descriptions

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| ID         | Part #     |    Type    |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 1          |     123    |      1     |
| 2          |     456    |      2     |
| 3          |     123    |      3     |
| 4          |     789    |      4     |
| 5          |     123    |      4     |
| 6          |     789    |      2     |
| 7          |     123    |      2     |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

I basically need to find any part number that has the Type Value of both '2' and '4', not one or the other.

I feel like it should be incredibly simple, but I can't seem to get correct results

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a combination of WHERE, GROUP BY and a HAVING clause to get the result. The key in the HAVING clause is to count the distinct items that are included in your WHERE filter:

```
select [part #]
from partDescriptions
where type in (2, 4)
group by [part #]
having count(distinct type) = 2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15a29/1)

If you want to return only the parts that have just type 2 and 4 nothing else, then you could expand on this:

```
select PartNum
from yourtable
where type in (2, 4)
  and partnum not in (select partnum
                      from yourtable 
                      where type not in (2, 4))
group by PartNum
having count(distinct type) = 2
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15a29/2)

Comment: This only works when there are exactly 2 part numbers with a `type` of 2 or 4. If another `part #` is added the query does not include it in the results. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81b96)

Comment: @Tony I am not sure I understand your comment, from the sample data it returns parts 123, 789. 123 has types 1, 2, 4 and 789 has 2, 4.  Feel free to elaborate.  The OP specifically requested to return all parts with both 2,4 as the types so if you add a part 1234 with type 2, they don't want it.

Comment: Actually I'm removing my down vote because I realise I misread the question, he wants `part #` where type is 2 AND 4. so my example would not need to be included in the results. (although SO won't let me remove the downvote now! Unless the answer is edited, oh well, I'm sure you can spare the 2 rep points @bluefeet ;)

Comment: @Yosi - Calm down, I thought the answer was incorrect but have re-read the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM PartDesciption P
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PartDesciption WHERE ID = P.ID AND Type = 2) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PartDesciption WHERE ID = P.ID AND Type = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
SELECT PartNumber, COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE Type IN (2, 4)
GROUP BY PartNumber HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: The one problem with this is if they have two entries for a part with type = 2, etc, this will return the part.

Comment: Yup, that's why I gave you a +1 for having the more accurate answer!

Answer (score 0):

You want part numbers that are missing neither of the two required values. The following query seems complicated, but it generalizes to similar requirements more easily than some of the simpler solutions to this kind of question.

If you have a table that lists all valid part numbers, you can use it in the outermost SELECT to avoid needing SELECT DISTINCT.

```
WITH RequiredParts(p) AS (
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 4
)
  SELECT DISTINCT([Part #]) AS [Part #]
  FROM [Part Descriptions] AS PD
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM RequiredParts AS RP
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM [Part Descriptions] AS PD2
      WHERE PD2.[Part #] = PD.[Part #]
      AND PD2.[Type] = RP.p
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for that tidbit, but unfortunately the example table has far less type values. Interesting approach though!